# How can I test context menu functionality in a web app?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, contextmenu, htmlunit, webdriver

I'm playing with a grails app that has a contextmenu (on right-click).
The context menu is built using Chris Domigan's [jquery contextmenu plugin](http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/).

While the contextmenus do actually work, I want to have automated tests, and I can't work out how to do it.

- I've tried Selenium 2.05a (ie. Webdriver), but there's no rightClick method.
- I notice that HtmlUnit has a rightclick method, but I don't seem to be able to detect any difference in the DOM between before the click and after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'd like to be able to do it in Internet Explorer or Firefox as well, the main usage will be HtmlUnit. It's nice that the HtmlUnit HtmlElement has a `rightClick()` method, but unfortunately it's `protected` and so not accessible from the WebDriver wrapped HtmlUnitWebElement.

I wrote a hack to make it accessible, and so now I can call rightClick(), although it only works if it's running with HtmlUnit - not IE or FF.

```
// Needs to be in this package to get access to the element
package org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;

public class OpenHtmlUnitWebElement extends HtmlUnitWebElement {

    // Provide a constructor, even though we don't really need it.
    public OpenHtmlUnitWebElement(HtmlUnitDriver parent, HtmlElement element) {
        super(parent, element);
    }

    // this is the method we really want.
    public static HtmlElement using(HtmlUnitWebElement huwe) {
        return huwe.element;
    }
}
```

Now my (groovy) test looks like this:

```
import static org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.OpenHtmlUnitWebElement.using

...

def itemWithContextMenu = driver.findElement(By.id('theId'))
if (itemWithContextMenu instanceOf HtmlUnitWebElement) {
  using(itemWithContextMenu).rightClick()
  def contextMenu = driver.findElement(By.id('jqContextMenu'))
  assert ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Currently there's no right click method in WebDriver, there's an enhancement request opened for it - http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=161

For now you can use keyboard shortcut Shift+F10 to simulate the right click on the element:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(....);
element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.F10));
```

Comment: Thanks ZloiAdun, but I'm still struggling. Depending on which element I send the Shift-F10 to, I either see the regular IE context menu, or the browser File menubutton is selected. I can't make my custom contextmenu appear. -- John.

Comment: Maybe you should try to show your menu via JavaScript? Something like
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("menu.display(...)");

I do not know the details of the menu that you are using, but there certainly should be some JavaScript function to display it

Answer (score 0):

if you use Ruby with Capybara, this one should be useful:

```
module Capybara
  module Node
    class Element
      def context_click
        @session.driver.browser.action.context_click(self.native).perform
      end
    end
  end
end
```