# How to save loaded picture resource using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Chrome as my browser, and I want to save a captcha to my computer with Selenium. Every time I request from the URL, I get a random image, but I need the one that is displayed on the browser so I can't request for it again.(Getting the src of the image then make another request like using `requests` will get a different image.)

Take this website as an example (The website I want to get the captcha from has a whitelist so I can't use that):
https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random

```
from selenium import webdriver

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'F:\Dev\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random')
    img = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('img')
```

Now I can see the picture in the browser, then what should I do to save the same picture to my computer as a file?

P.S.

- `img.screenshot('image.png')` doesn't work on the website with the captcha.
- Saving the whole screenshot of the page works, but please let me know a better solution.

Comment: It looks like it might be easier to take a screenshot since the url is the same but it generates a different image every time. [Previous Suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893904/how-to-save-an-image-by-selecting-save-image-as-in-a-context-menu-using-sel)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you element's screenshot

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('element selector here').screenshot_as_png
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about Chrome, but I was able to do the same on Firefox browser.
The code goes like this:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    import requests
    driver=webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("http/https://your website")
    img=driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath leading to your element")#locating element
    src=img.get_attribute('src')#fetch the location of image
    img=requests.get(src)#fetch image
    with open('image.jpg','wb') as writer:#open for writing in binary mode
        writer.write(img.content)#write the image
```

Comment: forgot to add a statement to close the browser. Hope you will add it along.